# Indexing in pytorch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I was looking further in source code of Vector Quantizer and found that kind of indexing that is totally new for me.

Here is the code:

```
back=torch.gather(used[None,:][inds.shape[0]*[0],:], 1, inds)
```

After trying with sample for tensor, what I understood here is the purpose:

`used[None,:][inds.shape[0]*[0],:]` will guarantee that input's first dimension will have same element as first dimension of inds.

`used[None,:][inds.shape[0]*[0],:]` have shape as `(inds.shape[0]*[0],:], used.shape[0], used.shape[1]...)`

I might be familiar with Ellipsis and Fancy Indexing, but this kind of variation is totally new for me.

My question is, how this mentioned indexing works and is there any variation else?